# Javascript regex match the last occurance

Tags: javascript, regex, string

**Question:**
Using regular expressions in javascript, if I have a string that contains zero or more newlines or carriage returns, what is the best way to tell how many characters are after the *last* newline or carriage return?

**Attempts:**
I've tried various regular expressions, but with no luck. Say I have the string:

"`_\nHELLO\nWORLD\nSALUTATIONS`"
In normal output, it looks like this:
`_
HELLO
WORLD
SALUTATIONS`

Shouldn't `/^(\r|\n){1}/g` find a string globally `g`, with only one occurance `{1}` of a return or newline `(\r|\n)`, or, in this case, "SALUTATIONS"? Instead no match is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your regex will find CRs/NLs only at the very beginning of the string, because you have an [`^`  anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) right there.

To find the last one, you rather will want to anchor your expression at the end of the string:

```
/[\r\n]([^\r\n]*)$/
```

By matching that, you will get all the characters after the last linebreak in the first capturing group.

Answer (score 4):

How about not using a regex

```
string.split(/\r|\n/).pop().length;
```

That splits the string on newlines, pops off the last one and get's the number of characters with `length`

Comment: does "pop" pull the last element in the array created by the split?

Comment: You should split on `/\r|\n/`, though

Comment: @Bergi - does any browser really use `\r` now? I know old IE used to return `\r\n`, and not just `\r`, but I didn't think this was an issue anymore ?

Comment: It might not be necessary, yes, but we don't know where the string came from and it's what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Bergi - sure, changed it, doesn't really matter to me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string.length - string.lastIndexOf('\n') - 1
```

Or if you really need to also check `\r`,

```
string.length - string.search(/[\n\r].*?$/) - 1
```

Comment: Should be `Math.max(string.lastIndexOf('\n'), string.lastIndexOf('\r'))`

Answer (score 0):

A short and simple way would be this

```
console.log(text.match(/.*$/)[0].length);
```

`$` marks the end of the string and by default `.` does not match line breaks, so the matched result is exactly the last line.